# Node.js on Ubuntu without NGINX or any other proxy is not preferable or even possible?

Tags: node.js, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

In simple node.js examples of https servers you can see following:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(8000);
```

But what is the point of .pem keys if nginx will manage SSL outside the app? You just proxy from nginx to http node.js app.

Why i can't find standalone node.js app example without any proxy? Is it not possible, or not usable?

Comment: *But what is the point of .pem keys if nginx will manage SSL outside the app?* - there's no point. *Why i can't find standalone node.js app example without any proxy* - because it's not practical to use it without reverse proxy in real life.

Comment: so .pem keys in node.js it's only for developing on windows?

Comment: The platform isn't relevant. There are Nginx, Apache and so on on Windows, too. I can't say what practical purpose pem keys serve here. The example just shows that it's possible to do this with Node alone.